# Confusion with C2061 error

Tags: c++

I'm confused as to what the syntax error is in this piece of code. Although I saw similar questions on the forum, all were related to header or preprocessing problems. If that is indeed the problem I would appreciate it if someone could point it out to me.

Specifically, the compiler says the error is in line 12, identifier 'i'

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    system("cls");
    int i = 0;
    while i < 5
        cout << "1"; Sleep(200);
        cout << "2"; Sleep(200);
        cout << "3"; Sleep(200);
        cout << "4"; Sleep(200);
        i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: And what does the error message say?

Comment: I find it a struggle to believe that any C++ book taught you to write loops in this manner. So why are you programming by guesswork? :)

Comment: When referring to compiler errors, always state the platform/compiler and give the text of the error. Don't expect people to go look up what a C2061 is.

Comment: By the way, get used to not clearing the screen.  There may be important data from prior executions of your program that you will need to see and clearing erases all of it.  Besides the command `cls` is not portable across all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

**This is not C++ syntax.**

`i < 5` is missing parentheses, and your entire loop is missing braces around the commands to run.

```
int main()
{
    system("cls");
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 5) {
        cout << "1"; Sleep(200);
        cout << "2"; Sleep(200);
        cout << "3"; Sleep(200);
        cout << "4"; Sleep(200);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Put down whatever book you're using and find a new one!

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loop needs braces.

```
while (i < 5)
{    
    cout << "1"; Sleep(200);
    cout << "2"; Sleep(200);
    cout << "3"; Sleep(200);
    cout << "4"; Sleep(200);
    i = i + 1;
}
```